# How do I search for a specific field in a CSV file given a corresponding user input?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

> Create a class that acts as the Parent class to each of these TV Show
> types: Family, Comedy, Dark, Mystery, Other.
>
> Each type of TV Show shall inherit from that Parent class.Determine
> what data and methods exist in the Parent and what exists in each
> childThere should be two constructors per child class. In the main()
> program, store all the TV Shows in an ArrayListUse a while
> loop to ask the user what show they want to ask a question of then
> answer questions that pertain to the TV Show.  Use the ArrayList to
> answer the questions. Provide the capability to the user to display
> all the TV Shows and the respective data.

So far I have managed to write a superclass and subclasses for each type of show and store the TV shows in an Array List. I am stuck on everything else.

A sample of the tvShowData.csv:

```
Title,audience ,network,actor 1,actor 2,actor 3,actor 4,TV Show Type
The Walking Dead,11.24,AMC,Norman Reedus,Andrew Lincoln,Lauren Cohan,Steven Yeun,Dark
Teen Wolf,3.02,MTV,Dylan O'Brien,Tyler Posey,Holland Roden,Tyler Hoechlin,Dark
```

```
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String file = "tvshowData.csv";
  List<List<String>> tvShows = new ArrayList<>();
  String line;
  String userInput;
  
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] shows = line.split(",");
          tvShows.add(Arrays.asList(shows));
     }
     System.out.println(tvShows);
  }
  System.out.println("Enter the TV Show you want to know about:");
  userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

// Superclass
public class TVShows
{
   private String title;
   private double audience;
   private String network;
   private String actor1, actor2, actor3, actor4;

   public TVShows(String title, double audience, String network)
   {
      this.title = title;
      this.audience = audience;
      this.network = network;
   }

   public TVShows(String actor1, String actor2, String actor3, String actor4)
   {
      this.actor1 = actor1;
      this.actor2 = actor2;
      this.actor3 = actor3;
      this.actor4 = actor4;
   }

   public String getTitle()
   {
      return title;
   }

   public double getAudience()
   {
      return audience;
   }

   public String network()
   {
      return network;
   }

   public String getActor1()
   {
      return actor1;
   }

   public String getActor2()
   {
      return actor2;
   }

   public String getActor3()
   {
      return actor3;
   }

   public String getActor4()
   {
      return actor4;
   }

}

// Subclass
public class Dark extends TVShows
{
    private String tvShowType;

    public Dark(String nameOfShow, double audience, String network)
    {
        super(nameOfShow, audience, network);
    }
   
    public Dark(String actor1, String actor2, String actor3, String actor4)
    {
        super(actor1, actor2, actor3, actor4);
    }
   
    public void setTvShowType(String tvShowType)
    {
        this.tvShowType = tvShowType;
    }
   
    public String getTvShowType()
    {
        return tvShowType;
    }
}
```

Comment: The user can ask specific details about a show such as the network it premieres on or the name of an actor.

Comment: The short and simple answer to "How do I search for a specific field" is to use a loop to scan through the array and check if the strings match `if(showString.equals(inputString)){...}` or contain the input `if(showString.contains(inputString)){...}`. The better answer as Abra mentioned is to create a custom class/object to store the data so that you can manage the data in an easier way.

Comment: @Abra I have created a TvShow superclass already and subclasses for each tv show type. I also stored the tv shows in Array List as specified in the prompt. I'm stuck on how I would take a user inputted tv show and a specific detail the user wants to know about that show and display it.

Comment: One hint, mainly you should have a constructor which contain all fields since it's used to get an instance with all fields populated, Using your constructors the instance is just partial populated with data (either actors or some other fields). Say use constructor which populate actors, then for title you should added manually after create the object. Seem lot's of extra work (assume you are aware that you cannot apply for the same object 2 constructors). Further more here specialization is a little bit redundant, just add an extra field on superclass (maybe enum : dark, etc)

Comment: Another hint, for actors you could just at end of csv all actors and you can get rid of restriction of have 4 actors as mandatory. Till actors, all fields are required and know the position where actors start. Use that to get a list of actors (say one show can have 30 actors so you have to write a 30 fileds and the contructor +30 params. Very verbose). `List of actors` can hold as many or less u wanted, Just look on the code provide at actors.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you could use something like, but you have to adapt with your inputs.

Matching is based on using various `predicates`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test();
    }

    public static void test() {
        //prepare data, here is just something for test 
        List<String> lst1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "B", "B");
        List<String> lst2 = Arrays.asList("A", "D", "E");
        ShowData sd1 = new Test().new ShowData("show1", lst1);
        ShowData sd2 = new Test().new ShowData("show2", lst2);
        // System.out.println(sd1);
        ShowList<ShowData> sl = new Test().new ShowList<ShowData>();
        sl.add(sd1);
        sl.add(sd2);

        //write searching criteria
        Predicate<String> pactorA = t -> t.equals("A");
        Predicate<ShowData> haveActorA = t -> t.actors.stream().filter(pactorA).count() > 0;
        System.out.println("[Count Lines for Actor A]=" + sl.stream().filter(haveActorA).count());
        //use criteria and print any matching-lines
        sl.stream().filter(haveActorA).forEach(System.out::println);

        //same as above but with other criteria[another actor]
        Predicate<String> pactorB = t -> t.equals("B");
        Predicate<ShowData> haveActorB = t -> t.actors.stream().filter(pactorB).count() > 0;
        System.out.println("[Count Lines for Actor B]=" + sl.stream().filter(haveActorB).count());
        sl.stream().filter(haveActorB).forEach(System.out::println);

        Predicate<String> pactorF = t -> t.equals("F");
        Predicate<ShowData> haveActorF = t -> t.actors.stream().filter(pactorF).count() > 0;
        System.out.println("[Count Lines for Actor F]=" + sl.stream().filter(haveActorF).count());
        sl.stream().filter(haveActorF).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    class ShowList<ShowData> extends ArrayList<ShowData> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    }

    class ShowData {
        String name;
        List<String> actors = new ArrayList<>();

        public ShowData(String name, List<String> actor) {
            this.name = name;
            this.actors.addAll(actor);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<String> getActors() {
            return actors;
        }

        public void setActors(List<String> actors) {
            this.actors = actors;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "name=" + name + " and actors=[" + actors.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
[Count Lines for Actor A]=2
name=show1 and actors=[A,B,C,B,B]
name=show2 and actors=[A,D,E]

[Count Lines for Actor B]=1
name=show1 and actors=[A,B,C,B,B]

[Count Lines for Actor F]=0
```